# Do iPads get location data when sleeping?

Tags: ios, ipad, gps, location

We are making an application which allows users to track their movement, and while it works fine with iPhones, it seems that whenever an iPad goes into sleep, it stops receiving location updates.  The location manager is linked to a timer that works as a background task, and fires consistently at a 4 minute mark (which is how it is designed to work), but on iPads (1st gen, 3G connected), even though the location manager is supposedly looking for data, the device never receives any location data.  Tested in conjunction with iPhones, the iPhones were tracking fine while the iPads were not.

**Is this a limitation of iPads (or of 1st gen iPads)?**

I can confirm that the background method is getting called through logs, and when location data is gotten, so the issue isn't that the timer isn't working or the background task isn't being executed.  It could be a problem where the background task doesn't have enough time to get locations before the system kills the task, but I do not think this is the case either (as even then, it should at least receive location data a few times in a day). Yes, of course the info plist has a tag for using location data in the background.